# iterate over fields using linq

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

I've got a table with alot of columns and want to concaternate all the string fields in a row together so I can perform a search through it without comparing the search string to each field in turn.

How do I iterate through the row without explicitly stating each column name?

```
ColumnA | ColumnB | ... | ColumnN
---------------------------------
   A    |    B    | ... |    N
```

I would like to get the result AB...N

This is what I have so far

```
string searchString = "text";
var searchCandidate = ATable.Where( ... condition ...); // IQueryable<ATable>
searchCandidate. // what goes here to loop through all fields ?
```

Comment: Please show the code that you currently have. In which data structure do you have the table?

Comment: not sure if i understood you correctly but i've added some info to the q..

Comment: From what context is `ATable`? LINQ2SQL? EF? A `DataTable`? ...?

Comment: it is linq to sql and the data type that linqpad shows is System.Data.Linq.Table.

Comment: Then you are out of luck with conventional methods, if the class that represents an entity (=row) doesn't expose an array of the column values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write such a method by building an expression tree as follows:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> AnyColumnContains<T> (string value)
{
    var p = Expression.Parameter (typeof (T), "entity");

    var fieldAccessors = typeof (T)
        .GetFields()
        .Where (f => f.FieldType == typeof (string))
        .Select (f => Expression.Field (p, f))
        .ToArray();

    var fieldArray = Expression.NewArrayInit (typeof (string), fieldAccessors); 

    var concatCall = Expression.Call (typeof (string).GetMethod (
        "Concat", new[] { typeof (string[]) }), fieldArray);

    var contains = Expression.Call (
        concatCall, 
        typeof (string).GetMethod ("Contains", new[] { typeof (string) } ),
        Expression.Constant (value));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>> (contains, p);
}
```

First, we get all the fields from the entity type (LINQPad uses fields to represent columns; you can change this to GetProperties for DataContexts generated in Visual Studio).

We need to create an expression that feeds these fields into a string.Concat statement. As the latter accepts an array of strings, we create an NewArrayInit expression to build up the array.

Next, we call the Concat method to join the strings together, and finally, the string.Contains method to test whether the string literal is in the expression that we built.

Here's how the method runs on AdventureWorks:

```
void Main()
{
    Addresses.Where (AnyColumnContains<Address> ("Seattle")).Dump();
}
```

Lambda translation:

```
Addresses
   .Where (
      entity => 
         String
            .Concat (new String[] { entity.AddressLine1, entity.AddressLine2,
                                    entity.City, entity.PostalCode } )
            .Contains ("Seattle")
   )
```

SQL translation:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = '%Seattle%'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[AddressID], [t0].[AddressLine1], [t0].[AddressLine2], [t0].[City],
       [t0].[StateProvinceID], [t0].[PostalCode], [t0].[rowguid] AS [Rowguid],
       [t0].[ModifiedDate]
FROM [Person].[Address] AS [t0]
WHERE ((([t0].[AddressLine1] + [t0].[AddressLine2]) + [t0].[City]) + [t0].[PostalCode])
      LIKE @p0
```

Comment: this is definitely on the right path, i still need to work out how to handle null fields and non string fields but that's homework so i can learn how to use expression trees. thanks joe! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22SYSTEM.LINQ.ENUMERABLE.AGGREGATE%60%601%22%29%3Bk%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29%3Bk%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29%3Bk%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29%3Bk%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true), if you have each row as an array of the values of the columns. This is the case with `DataTable`.

Comment: i've only managed to use the aggregate function to iterate through one field over many different rows so one column so to speak. how do you iterate over one row? or many fields in a row?

Comment: @Joe: As I said in my comment to your question, this is only possible, if each row exposes its values as an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn { DataType = typeof(int), ColumnName = "A" });
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn { DataType = typeof(int), ColumnName = "b" });
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn { DataType = typeof(string), ColumnName = "c" });
        DataRow r;
        for (int i=0;i<=5 ;i++)
        {
            r = dt.NewRow();
            r["A"] = i;
            r["b"] = i + 2;
            r["c"] = i.ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(r);

        }
        var query = from DataRow row in dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList()
                    let textUnion = GetFields(row)
                    select new { textUnion };
        dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();

    }
    string GetFields(DataRow row)
    {
        StringBuilder retValue=new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < row.ItemArray.Length;i++ )
        {
            retValue.Append(Convert.ToString(row[i]));
        }

        return retValue.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: hum... problem is, mine is not a datatable. it's of type System.Linq.IQueryable.

Comment: i'm not sure how it's declared, i'm using linqpad and it creates the object internally. i just use the linqtosql table that it makes